# C++ / Qt скачать файл с веб-сервера

Tags: c++, qt, download

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функционал скачки файла с веб-сервера? Интересуют два варианта: один для Qt, если такой существует, а второй на чистых "плюсах". Только желательно поподробней, как для шестилетнего ребенка )
Файл нужно скачать в папку с программой. В определенную папку т. е., а не куда-нибудь в Downloads.

Comment: Совсем "чисто" не получится, нет в стандарте С++ работы с сетями. Придется использовать какие-то библиотеки, API операционной системы (кстати, какой?)... И опять же, какой функционал? Для работы с http, https? Ссылка хотя бы прямо на файл, не надо разбор страницы и интерпретацию JS писать? Что значит "как для шестилетнего" — с описанием самого протокола, например? Как у Шекли — "чтобы правильно задать вопрос, надо знать половину ответа"...

Comment: Пример, на основе qt: https://github.com/Infernno/qt5-examples/blob/master/network/download/main.cpp

Comment: Никаких js. Задачи такие... Первый замысел - это нечто вроде домашней облачной системы, чтобы папка Sourcec автоматически копировалась на сервер и оттуда загружалась на другие компы. Допустим, я сижу в комнате, пишу программу. Затем собираюсь и еду куда-нибудь, например, на дачу или на работу. Мне бы очень хотелось чтобы папка Sources была и там, вместе с тем же содержимым что и на домашнем компе. Ну, это в общих чертах.

Comment: Второй вариант использования - это система автоматизации обновления приложения. Допустим, запускаю я свою программу. Она подключается к серверу, скачивает файл с каким-то индексом, сравнивает... Если индекс больше вшитого в нее эталона, тогда инициируется скачивание и установка этого приложения.

Comment: Операционка - это Debian-подобное нечто. Преимущественно, Ubuntu.

Comment: "Как для шестилетнего" - это значит максимально просто и наглядно. Например, я тут недавно обратился к другу-программисту и он сказал мне что-то типа "В C# я передавал аудиофайл методом write line и read line", далее уточнил что передача шла через TCP-сокет. Что я должен был понять из этого? Я ничего не понял. Мне нужен пример! Детально разжевывать принцип работы самого протокола, наверно, не обязательно. Шестилетним детям такое рано )

Answer (score 0):

А вот и пример для C++ подъехал.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

int main(void) {
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
char *url = "https://madmentat.ru/files/testfile";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "testfile";
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}
return 0;
}
```

При компиляции в Ubuntu 20.04 возникла ошибка, типа того что не найдена  библиотека curl. Ее ее действительно нет, ее надо установить, а затем при следующей компиляции указать соответствующий аргумент:

```
g++ downloader.cpp -lcurl -o downloader
```